Hopcroft-Karp algorithm - about marking nodes as visited in the dfs part
In this implementation of Hopcroft-Karp (graph is a list[list[int]], adjacency list):
pair_u: list[int] = [-1] * n
pair_v: list[int] = [-1] * n
dist: list[int] = [0] * n

def bfs() -> bool:
    queue: deque[int] = deque()
    for u in u_nodes:
        if pair_u[u] == -1:
            dist[u] = 0
            queue.append(u)
        else:
            dist[u] = 10**9
    dist_found: int = 10**9
    while queue:
        u = queue.popleft()
        if dist[u] < dist_found:
            for v in graph[u]:
                if pair_v[v] == -1:
                    # unmatched v node, augmenting path found yay
                    dist_found = dist[u]
                elif dist[pair_v[v]] == 10**9:
                    dist[pair_v[v]] = dist[u] + 1
                    queue.append(pair_v[v])
    return dist_found != 10**9

def dfs(u_: int) -> bool:
    for v_ in graph[u_]:
        if pair_v[v_] == -1 or (dist[pair_v[v_]] == dist[u_] + 1 and dfs(pair_v[v_])):
            pair_u[u_] = v_
            pair_v[v_] = u_
            dist[u_] = 10**9  # mark as visited BUT OPTIONAL????
            return True
    dist[u_] = 10**9  # mark as visited
    return False

matching: int = 0
while bfs():
    for u in u_nodes:
        if pair_u[u] == -1:
            if dfs(u):
                matching += 1

print(matching)

Why is this line:
            dist[u_] = 10**9  # mark as visited BUT OPTIONAL????

optional?
I see in standard implementations that it's not there but for me I should add it, and it works in both ways. My reasoning is that this line should be here because once we find an augmenting path, we don't want to re-use any of the nodes for other augmenting paths of the same length ("The algorithm finds a maximal set of vertex DISJOINT augmenting paths of length k" Wikipedia). Or maybe we are allowed to add augmenting paths that are overlapping with each other (would make sense, every time we get +1 but then I don't understand why they mention DISJOINT on Wikipedia)?
I would love some clarification on that.

This is optional for the following reason. You come to this line when you match u_ and v_. Note that dfs is called for $u$-vertices only. What would happen if you don't mark u_ as visited? You can't call dfs(u_) from the main function before the next call of bfs, because only non-matched $u$-vertices become arguments there. On the other hand you can't call dfs(u_) from dfs(u_') (before the next call of bfs), because there is no u_' adjacent to v_ such that dist[u_] = dist[pair_v[v_]] = dist[u_'] + 1. Otherwise either old pair of v_ would have distance less by $1$ and u_ and v_ wouldn't be matched, or the same controversy would appear at earlier part of path from an unmatched $u$-vertex. That's why an explicit label of being visited is not obligatory.
Edit. To explain the statement about controversy firstly we need to determine what bfs is doing. Based on the given graph $G$ it considers the following directed graph $H$ on the same vertices: there is an arc $v_1u_1$ in $H$ if edge $u_1v_1$ belong to current matching in $G$ and there is an arc $u_1v_2$ if such edge belong to graph $G$, but not to the current matching. It guarantees that any path in $H$ from unmatched $u$-vertex to unmatched $v$-vertex is alternating. And dist[u_] equals to the half of edge-distance from the nearest unmatched $u$-vertex. So when vertices u_ and v_ are matched vertex v_ still only has incoming arcs from $u$-vertices with dist-label greater than or equal to dist[u_]. Indeed, old pair of v_ (if exists) has dist-label dist[u_] + 1 according to the if-statement. So there is no $u$-vertex adjacent to $v$ with smaller dist-label. If v_ was unmatched then dist[u_] equals to the value of dist_found in the last bfs call and for similar reasoning there is no $u$-vertex adjacent to v_ with smaller dist-label.

Thanks for the answer, I'm struggling to understand the second part: there is no u_' adjacent to v_ such that dist[u_] = dist[pair_v[v_]] = dist[u_'] + 1. Maybe let's look at this example to highlight what I'm confused about (forgive my terrible drawing): https://i.imgur.com/8gMX083.png. Dotted lines are edges that can be taken but not in our matching (yet). It seems to me that $u_3$ is in two augmenting paths and we would "need" to mark it as visited?

Ah no I just realized I think I understand, after the first augmenting path is found, pair_v[$v_2$] doesn't point to $u_3$ anymore ... Is that it?

Could you expand on the proof regarding "because there is no u_' adjacent to v_ such that dist[u_] = dist[pair_v[v_]] = dist[u_'] + 1". I can't find any counter examples but I'm struggling to understand that proof by contradiction you're making.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows I added more detailed explanation

Thank you so much, the last three/four sentences really helped.
